# Spring MVC - race conditions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose I have the following Spring MVC controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksController {

  @Autowired    
  private final BooksRepository booksRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
  public Collection<Book> doSearch(@RequestBody final SearchCriteria criteria) {
    return booksRepository.find(criteria);
  }
}
```

and the following repository

```
@Service
public class BooksRepository {

  @Autowired
  private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private final SearchQueryBuilder searchQueryBuilder;

  public Collection<BookLite> find(final SearchCriteria criteria) {

    // TODO: will this cause race conditions?
    searchQueryBuilder.clear().addKeywords(criteria.getKeywords());

    final String query = searchQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
    final Object[] params = searchQueryBuilder.buildParams();

    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, params, new BookExtractor());
  }
}
```

with the following `SearchQueryBuilder` implementation

```
@Component
public class SearchQueryBuilder {

  private final List<String> keywords = new LinkedList<String>();

  public SearchQueryBuilder clear() {
    keywords.clear();
    return this;
  }

  public SearchQueryBuilder addKeywords(final List<String> keywords) {
    for (String keyword : keywords) {
        add(keyword);
    }
    return this;
  }

  private SearchQueryBuilder add(final String keyword) {
    keywords.add(keyword);
    return this;
  }

  public String buildQuery() {
    ...
  }

  public Object[] buildParams() {
    ...
  }
}
```

My concerns are the following. Since the SearchQueryBuilder class is not thread safe, injecting it this way will probably cause race conditions. What is a good way to handle this? Is it enough (and a good practice) to change the bean scope to e.g. request?

Comment: Yes, you have a race condition. Why not simply use a generated Spring repository instead of hand-writing it?

Comment: Do you mean Spring Data JPA? Thanks

Comment: Why do you even define your builder as managed bean (`@Component`)? Why not just create with `new` every time you need to build something?

Comment: I do not see the reason for making the spring container manage the search query builder in this example. You should rather just instantiate a new builder when required. Is there a reason for managing the SearchQueryBuilder instantiation with spring?

Comment: I just wanted to gain the advantages of dependency injection.

Comment: There is no benefit in injecting everything at all costs. Builders like this are nothing more than a *syntactic sugar*. You don't need their implementation to be interchangeable. And if you do need that go for Alexander's answer (i.e. define builder factory).

Comment: IoC / dependency injection is a very nice feature, but its main purpose is to manage lifecycle and interconnect main application components. If a single bean needs to create `StringBuilder` to achieve its goal, it should create it... there is no benefit in having `StringBuilder` follow application lifecycle (such nonsense example is intentional).

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong with using new to create instances when its required, however if you want it to look fancy try method injection. http://java.dzone.com/articles/method-injection-spring

Answer (score 1):

I would use SearchQueryBuilderFactory as a Spring bean, and create the SearchQueryBuilder instances on the fly. 
I would avoid creating Spring beans that change state during the execution. 
 
Your reliance on having them request-scoped makes your solution more fragile and error-prone, since the problem would reappear if you try to use it as Spring bean outside the web context.

Comment: apparently you dont know what "request-scoped" means, thats simply an indicator for instatiation - the bean-instance will be created at the beginning of a HTTP-request and destroyed upon completion; theres no usability-limitation of any kind hence "less usable outside of the web context" doesnt make much sense.

Comment: @specializt apparently you have not tried to use request scoped beans without the actual request scope ;).

Comment: um ... thats nonsense. Please stop assuming things and please stop making things up. Even request-scoped spring beans can manually be instantiated, spring beans are standard java objects -- absolutely no magic there.

Comment: If you try to use your `@Scope("request")` bean out of request thread you will end up with exception. Btw. nice attitude.

Comment: trying to use java objects which arent instantiated is a beginners' mistake. Blaming a framework for your own lack of knowledge and experience is ... well ... lets not get into that. I recommend re-opening your textbooks.

Comment: I was not clear enough with 'less usable outside of the web context', so I have hopefully clarified my answer now. Thanks specializt to pointing to this. Yet the usability limitation does exist since the problem would reappear once you try to use it as Spring bean outside the web context. My point was that this kind of classes should not be used as Spring beans at all.